# crear borde al final de la imagen dentro de un carousel

Tags: bootstrap, css3

estoy tratando de colocar un borde de color azul al final de las imagenes que se encuentran dentro del carousel, pero no he podido,  este es mi codigo html del carousel.  como podria agregar dicho borde?

```
    <div class="row fila2">

<div class="col-12 imagenesc">

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="imagenes/20130819180556.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item ">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="imagenes/20130819180644.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
        </div>
```

[image: aqui] pongo una captura de la imagen de la web, arriba tengo dos bordes, quiero que al final de la imagen, aparezca el borde, pero no he podido dar.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien como seria agregar un borde al final? Que queres decir? Y que libreria estas usando para hacer tu carousel?

Comment: estoy utilizando bootstrap 4

Comment: Es decir, ¿un borde a la derecha **de cada imagen** dentro del carousel? ¿Qué tal `.carousel img { border-right: 2px solid #00bbff; }`?

Comment: el borde tiene que ir despues de la imagen es decir al final del div

Comment: el borde que esta al comienzo de la imagen es azul, y al fina igual azul tambien, el de arriba esta, pero el de abajo no he dado como

Comment: ¿Por qué simplemente no le das el `border-bottom` al carousel?

Comment: no funciona guz, he hecho de todo